# route an external ip to an internal ip windows server 2008

Tags: routes, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a windows server 2008 server with 2 network card

Network card one -> ISP router (ip: 192.168.1.70, mask: 255.255.255.0)

NC2 -> Switch -> Computers  (ip: 10.10.10.2, gateway:10.10.10.1)

I have configured domain controller and Network policy and Access Services and I have 2 pc connected to this domain. I also have set a small NASC server (fujitsu box) that has a web interface and have set it to the ip 10.10.10.70. What I want is to access it remotely.

I know how can I open a port on my ISP router lets say I have opened port 1111 for 192.168.1.50. How can I link this ip  to my internal ip 10.10.10.70:8080

also should I open the ports to windows firewall in windows server 2008?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Port mapping  is done on public ip and local Ips.
lets say you have 30.30.30.30 ip on your router that is connected to ISP
and your local network is 10.10.10.0
so the mapping will be like this 
30.30.30.30:1111   ---> 10.10.10.40{you machine local ip}
or in reverse case
10.10.10.40{you machine local ip}:30.30.30.30

try implementing it like this. it should work.

Alternatively, search this software for your OS and try this one .. 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/pjs-passport/

software name: passport.

Answer (score 0):

In your windows 2008, go to routing and remote access, go to IPV4, NAT, select the external network adapter, right click, properties.

Go to the third tab (ports and services) click add
give a name (like fujitzu)
TCP
incoming port: 1111
private address: 10.10.10.70
port 8080

I assume that you have already opened the 1111 port on your router